# Sequelize referencing to wrong foreign key

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, orm, sequelize.js

There are two tables which are Transaction and Transaction Details. The recordId is a foreign key of Transaction Details.

I am trying to find a Transaction by recordId and then include the Transaction Details. A Transaction can have many Transaction Details. Here are my codes:

```
db.models.Transaction.hasMany(db.models.TransactionDetails, {
    foreignKey: 'recordId'
});
```

And then I'm querying a findOne and it looks like this:

```
db.models.Transaction.findOne({
            where: {
                recordId: req.query.recordid
            } ,
            include: [{
                model: db.models.TransactionDetails
            }]
            
        })
```

But when I sent the request on Postman, the JSON data looked like this:

```
{
"error": false,
"message": {
    "id": "8151",
    "recordId": "6688",
    "transactionNo": "1563804469415",
    "cashierId": "4",
    "payType": "cash",
    "terminalNo": "0012346",
    "amount": 40,
    "discount": 0,
    "cardNo": "none",
    "transDate": "2019-07-22T14:23:26.000Z",
    "createdAt": "2019-07-22T14:20:19.679Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-07-22T14:20:19.679Z",
    "pt-transactions-details": [
        {
            "id": "38048",
            "recordId": "8151", //this is wrong, the recordId must be the same as above which is 6688
            "transId": "3731",
            "productId": "539",
            "quantity": "1",
            "amount": 60,
            "terminal": "002789",
            "createdAt": "2019-09-13T01:22:48.349Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-09-13T01:22:48.349Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "9921",
            "recordId": "8151", //this is wrong, the recordId must be the same as above which is 6688
            "transId": "3985",
            "productId": "1061",
            "quantity": "2",
            "amount": 100,
            "terminal": "0012346",
            "createdAt": "2019-07-05T03:44:49.406Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-07-05T03:44:49.406Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "68848",
            "recordId": "8151", //this is wrong, the recordId must be the same as above which is 6688
            "transId": "5358",
            "productId": "1128",
            "quantity": "1",
            "amount": 160,
            "terminal": "171412",
            "createdAt": "2019-10-15T13:00:03.864Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-10-15T13:00:03.864Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Can someone help me regarding this? I already spent a day trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, you need to pass `sourceKey` into `hasMany` method.

```js
Transaction.hasMany(TransactionDetail, { foreignKey: 'recordId', sourceKey: 'recordId' });
```

Long answer, here is an example:

`index.ts`:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import assert from 'assert';

class Transaction extends Model {}
Transaction.init(
  {
    recordId: {
      unique: true,
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'transactions' },
);

class TransactionDetail extends Model {}
TransactionDetail.init(
  {
    amount: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'transaction_details' },
);

Transaction.hasMany(TransactionDetail, { foreignKey: 'recordId', sourceKey: 'recordId' });

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    await Transaction.create(
      { recordId: '6688', transaction_details: [{ amount: 60 }, { amount: 100 }, { amount: 160 }] },
      { include: [TransactionDetail] },
    );

    const rval = await Transaction.findOne({ where: { recordId: '6688' }, include: [TransactionDetail] });
    console.log(rval.dataValues);
    assert.equal(rval.transaction_details.length, 3, 'transaction details count should equal 3');
    const transactionDetailsDataValues = rval.transaction_details.map((d) => d.dataValues);
    console.log('transactionDetailsDataValues: ', transactionDetailsDataValues);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

The execution result of above code:

```sh
{ id: 1,
  recordId: '6688',
  transaction_details:
   [ transaction_details {
       dataValues: [Object],
       _previousDataValues: [Object],
       _changed: {},
       _modelOptions: [Object],
       _options: [Object],
       isNewRecord: false },
     transaction_details {
       dataValues: [Object],
       _previousDataValues: [Object],
       _changed: {},
       _modelOptions: [Object],
       _options: [Object],
       isNewRecord: false },
     transaction_details {
       dataValues: [Object],
       _previousDataValues: [Object],
       _changed: {},
       _modelOptions: [Object],
       _options: [Object],
       isNewRecord: false } ] }
transactionDetailsDataValues:  [ { id: 1, amount: 60, recordId: '6688' },
  { id: 2, amount: 100, recordId: '6688' },
  { id: 3, amount: 160, recordId: '6688' } ]
```

Check the data record in the database:

```sh
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "transactions";
 id | recordId
----+----------
  1 | 6688
(1 row)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "transaction_details";
 id | amount | recordId
----+--------+----------
  1 |     60 | 6688
  2 |    100 | 6688
  3 |    160 | 6688
(3 rows)
```

Sequelize version: `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/node-sequelize-examples/tree/master/src/examples/stackoverflow/60446814

Comment: hi i have a follow up question, how to access the keys on pt-transactions-details based on the JSON data that i showed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define Sequelize association as mentioned below -

```
db.models.Transaction.belongsTo(db.models.TransactionDetails, {
    foreignKey: 'recordId', targetKey: 'recordId'
});
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, it still outputs the same JSON data :(

Comment: Does the column definition in the database itself (which is postgresql) affects the way my program behaves? Because the PK assigned to the Transaction table is 'id' not 'recordId'. I'm sorry I'm new to this and this work is only passed to me